# Sequelize: order before applying imit

Tags: javascript, orm, sequelize.js

My query is sorting the array after the limit has been set, so the array is not sorted properly thus returning wrong data. I want to sort the array by associated object's date attribute, and after that, limit the array and use the offset.

```js
await dbBooking.findAll({
                include: [
                    {
                        model: dbEvent,
                        attributes: defaultEventsAttributes,
                        include: [
                            {
                                model: dbUser,
                                through: { attributes: [] },
                                attributes: defaultUsersAttributes,
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
                order: [['event', 'startTime', 'ASC']],
                offset: offset,
                limit: 6,
                attributes: defaultBookingsAttributes,
            });
```

The SQL Query without subQuery:false

```sql
SELECT `booking`.*,
       `event`.`id`           AS `event.id`,
       `event`.`title`        AS `event.title`,
       `event`.`description`  AS `event.description`,
       `event`.`starttime`    AS `event.startTime`,
       `event`.`endtime`      AS `event.endTime`,
       `event->users`.`id`    AS `event.users.id`,
       `event->users`.`email` AS `event.users.email`
FROM   (SELECT `booking`.`id`,
               `booking`.`totalprice`,
               `booking`.`eventid`
        FROM   `bookings` AS `booking`
        LIMIT  0, 6) AS `booking`
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `events` AS `event`
                    ON `booking`.`eventid` = `event`.`id`
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `eventusers` AS `event->users->eventuser`
                         INNER JOIN `users` AS `event->users`
                                 ON `event->users`.`id` =
                                    `event->users->eventuser`.`userid`)
                    ON `event`.`id` = `event->users->eventuser`.`eventid`
ORDER  BY `event`.`starttime` ASC;
```

`subQuery: false`

```sql
SELECT `booking`.`id`,
       `booking`.`totalprice`,
       `event`.`id`           AS `event.id`,
       `event`.`title`        AS `event.title`,
       `event`.`description`  AS `event.description`,
       `event`.`starttime`    AS `event.startTime`,
       `event`.`endtime`      AS `event.endTime`,
       `event->users`.`id`    AS `event.users.id`,
       `event->users`.`email` AS `event.users.email`
FROM   `bookings` AS `booking`
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `events` AS `event`
                    ON `booking`.`eventid` = `event`.`id`
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `eventusers` AS `event->users->eventuser`
                         INNER JOIN `users` AS `event->users`
                                 ON `event->users`.`id` =
                                    `event->users->eventuser`.`userid`)
                    ON `event`.`id` = `event->users->eventuser`.`eventid`
ORDER  BY `event`.`starttime` ASC
LIMIT  0, 6;
```

associations

```
Booking.belongsTo(User);
Booking.belongsTo(Event);
User.belongsToMany(Event, {
    through: { model: EventUsers, unique: false },
    foreignKey: 'userId',
});
Event.belongsToMany(User, {
    through: { model: EventUsers, unique: false },
    foreignKey: 'eventId',
});
```

Comment: Did you try `subQuery: false`?

Comment: yes, did not work at all

Comment: Your Sequelize query doesn't match SQL query. Can you show the SQL query for this simplified version of Sequelize query?

Comment: @Anatoly the question is updated

Comment: And with `sunQuery: false` please

Comment: `subQuery: false`  returns `bookings` with the same `id` grouped by  `event.users`

Comment: Wait, can you add model associations as well? I suspect you have `Booking.hasMany(Event`

Comment: @Anatoly check the associations above

Comment: The second SQL query looks much better though I don't get it why users query is not a separate query (because of many-to-many)

Comment: Are you trying to fetch 6 (distinct) Bookings?   `subQuery: false` will apply limit to the joined result table, so it will be returning `# of Bookings * # of Users <= 6`.  If you want to have 6 Bookings, you probably need to separate the query.

Comment: @Emma How do I separate the query?

Comment: I want to fetch 6 distinct bookings but before limiting I need to order them

Comment: You can first query 6 Bookings order by events to fetch Booking ids.  Then in second query, fetch all Bookings and nested associations with `where: { id: { [Op.in]:  idsFrom1stQuery }}`